# How to create a Semester in a period that must be greater than the Semester that already exists in .Net Core?

Tags: datetime, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, repository-pattern

I am having a `Semester1` including `StartDate1` and `EndDate1`. I want to create a new `Semester2` and it must ensure `EndDate1` < `StartDate2`. How can I compare them?

I am using .Net Core 5 and Repository pattern

If you have any guidance please let me know. And if you need more information about the Code please tell me.

**Repo** The comparisons below are made by me inside a semester

```
    public SemesterViewModel CreateSemester(Semester semester)
    {
        
        if (Semester.SemesterStartDate <Semester.SemesterClosureDate &&
            Semester.SemesterClosureDate < Semester.SemesterEndDate)
        {
            var newSemester = new Semester
            {
                SemesterName = Semester.SemesterName,
                SemesterStartDate = Semester.SemesterStartDate,
                SemesterClosureDate = Semester.SemesterClosureDate,
                SemesterEndDate = Semester.SemesterEndDate
            };
            _dbContext.Semesters.Add(newSemester);
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Do you not want to allow semsters to overlap each other in general no matter how many semesters there already are? Or is Semester1 in this example a specific semester that you identify by some other condition?

Comment: I want all of my `Semester` not to overlap.

Comment: All Semester s are randomly generated and no Semester has been correctly identified before.

Comment: Do you have any ideas about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after reviewing your repo. i am updating my answer. I can see that you're trying to compare the dates between semester 1 and semester 2. But here you're just comparing dates of semester 2 which won't work.

You should first get semester1 from db and then compare the date with that.

```
var semester1 = GetSemester(); //get semester 1;
```

So if you want to compare with last semester than:

```
var semester1 = Get().OrderByDescending(a => a.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

and then:

```
if (semester1 == null || (semesterViewModel.Semester.SemesterStartDate > semester1.SemesterEndDate))
{
    //save newSemester 
}
```

Comment: I tried it and maybe it succeeded, however when I remove all the Semester and recreate it it shows a Null error

Comment: I have updated the check in the answer, you need to add null check on semester1

Comment: I was successful. Wish you fun evening.